# Analogy to explain why an antenna must be (in order) size of wavelength

Tags: antenna, basic, wave

An antenna has to be sized on the order of the wavelength because we want waves to form. Waves mean, very roughly speaking, different "state" (current, voltage, water level, ...) at different locations at different times.

This means that the structure must be long enough such that the signal propagation is visible. If the signal would propagate infinitely fast, it would change as a function of time only but not as a function of location. No wave forms.

Alternatively, the signal propagation speed must be slow.

I am looking for a good analogy to explain the latter (reducing propagation speed reduces required structure size) to a non-technical person. I was thinking about a swimming pool and the comparing it to one with oil. However, I do not see how I would convince someone to imagine creating a 1m wave in a 1cm pool ;-)

I expect this question will generate a lot of answers. I emphasize that I am only interested in completely non-technical (and not necessarily perfect) layman analogies. Available videos or animations would make it even much better.

Comment: Compare it to a water pipe.  If there is a short gap, it will still spring out water but the longer the gap , the more water radiate until you reach geometric echoes or resonant wave like 1/4w and its multiples which affect the apparent impedance more significantly if out of phase or in phase.

Comment: I think I don't understand ;-) Can you elaborate? The water pipe is closed? It contains waves of length lambda? I punch in a hole of length lambda/100 and water "springs out"? I create a hole of length "lambda/4" and "all" water will go through the gap? How do I incorporate the propagation speed? Oil instead of water?

Comment: Consider it is under max pressure and goes at the max speed of that dielectric or viscosity.  Water is actually polar so it has very low speed due to permeability =80 vs oil = plastic =4 and air=1. So speed is inverse to square root of permeability.  Air will leak out or transmit fastest, water = 9x slower, but this analog is weak.

Comment: There's no suitable analogy to how the current in a conductor couples to EM waves. It just is that when you solve the antenna far field equation, you just get way less power out if the antenna isn't the right shape.